# Configurar tabela HTML, usando a estrutura 'for' do python django

Tags: html, python, django

Estou fazendo uma tabela através de 3 listas geradas na views, mas não consigo deixar a tabela configurada corretamento no html, seriam 3 colunas e 60 linhas, mas elas não ficam ajustadas corretamente, segue meu código HTML:

```
       <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Horario</td>
                <td>Ligado</td>
                <td>Desligado</td>
            </tr>
            {% for x in teste4 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ x }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for y in tabela1 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ y }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            {% for z in tabela2 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ z }}<td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}


        </table>
```

Gera esse resultado(diminui o tamanho para caber na imagem)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o código que gera essa tabela:

```
    x = PrettyTable(["Horario", "Ligado", "Desligado"])
    x.align["Horario"] = "2"
    x.align["Ligado"] = "2"
    x.align["Desligado"] = "r"
    x.padding_width = 1
    z=0
    while z < len(teste4):
        x.add_row([teste4[z], tabela1[z], tabela2[z]])
        z = z + 1
    print (x)
```

**EDIT**

Conforme falado nos comentarios alterei a views para passar um método e a tabela gerada tambem deu errado, segue código e imagem

```
    x = PrettyTable(["Horario", "Ligado", "Desligado"])
    x.align["Horario"] = "2"
    x.align["Ligado"] = "2"
    x.align["Desligado"] = "r"
    x.padding_width = 1
    z=0
    while z < len(teste4):
        x.add_row([teste4[z], tabela1[z], tabela2[z]])
        z = z + 1
    print (x)
    passar = x.get_html_string()
```

com o html ficando Tabela:{{ passar }}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A estrutura da sua tabela no HTML está bem errada. Você está inserindo elementos `<tr>` dentro de elementos `<td>`, que já estão dentro de `<tr>`. Na tabela, você sempre define uma linha por vez, ou seja, para cada `<tr>` você terá um ou mais `<td>` e este elemento **não pode** ter `<tr>` dentro.

Comment: Sim eu ja fiz com a estrutura certa, mas o resultado sai pior do que esta na pergunta, por incrivel que pareça com essa estrutura é onde eu consegui o resultado mais parecido com oq eu quero, mas arrumei a pergunta com a estrutura certa

Comment: Como comentado na sua outra pergunta, basta utilizar o método `get_html_string` do `PrettyTable`.

Comment: Até agora nao entendi como usar esse metodo

Comment: Ele retorna uma *string* com todo o código HTML da sua tabela, é só exibir.

Comment: Por curiosidade, por que possui duas contas, [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/118738/guilherme) e [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/141733/guilherme), distintas no site? Criou uma nova por engano?

Comment: tentei aqui e retornou errado, vou editar a pergunta com o metodo e seu retorno, sobre as duas contas, eu uso uma em cada pc, quando criei um nao lembrava que tinha no outro, fazi tempo que nao usava

Comment: E se você fizer `{{ passar|safe }}`?

Comment: opa, ai deu certo, muito obrigado, só uma duvida, tem como eu deixar os campos da tabela mais espaçados entre eles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já citado, o método mais fácil é utilizar `get_html_string` do `PrettyTable`, pois ele já retorna, como *string*, todo o código HTML da sua tabela.

Porém, como padrão, o Django escapa os valores injetados nos *templates* como forma de prevenir alguns tipos de ataque, como XSS. Para conseguir exibir corretamente a sua tabela, será necessário indicar que o valor injetado é seguro fazendo, no seu *template*:

```
{{ passar|safe }}
```

Para mais detalhes do filtro `safe`, [veja a documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe).